# How to get stdout and stderr of a github actions step

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a job, there is a step called "Terraform Plan" with an id of "plan". I want to be print the stdout and stderr of this step. But unfortunately i'm not able to fetch that information.

**echo ${{ toJSON(steps.plan) }}**

```
  echo {
    "outputs": {
      "tfplan_identifier": "tfplan-expected"
    },
    "outcome": "failure",
    "conclusion": "success"
  }
```

How do i get the stdout and stderr. `${{ steps.plan.outputs.stderr }}` is returning null.

````
  plan:
    needs: [conflict, format, validate, lint, security]
    name: plan
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      tfplan_identifier: ${{ steps.plan.outputs.tfplan_identifier }}
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Configure AWS Credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
      with:
        aws-region: us-east-2
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.TERRAFORM_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.TERRAFORM_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
    - name: Setup Terraform
      uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
      with:
        terraform_version: 1.3.7
        terraform_wrapper: false
    - name: Terraform Init
      id: init
      run: terraform init -backend-config=prod.s3.tfbackend
    - name: Terraform Workspace
      run: terraform workspace select prod || terraform workspace new prod 
    - name: Terraform Plan
      id: plan
      continue-on-error: true
      run: |
        tfplan_identifier=tfplan-expected
        echo "tfplan_identifier=$tfplan_identifier" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
        terraform plan -var-file="prod.tfvars" -input=false -no-color -out=${tfplan_identifier}
        terraform show -no-color tfplan-actual > plan.log
    - name: Output
      run: |
        echo ${{ toJSON(steps.plan) }}
        echo ${{ steps.plan.outputs.stderr }}

    ```
````

Comment: STDOUT and STDERR are not available via `outputs`. You have to set those as part of your step. You're using the default [shell](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell) invocation which may fail as soon as an error occurs. Instead, you can wrap your commands into a script, handle success and failure cases, then redirect to STDOUT or STDERR accordingly, and finally set those as `outputs` (maybe, the filenames or the complete string outputs).